# Passing Data through Line of Filters using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects which I want to pass this list through a set of filters, the very important thing here I want to mention is the filtred set from the first filter will be the input set of the second till the last filter.

Here is my filter Function signature:

`IEnumerable<string> Filter(IEnumerable<string> data);`

I did it with for loop, so I want a result similar to this foreach loop using, but I want to do it in a more declarative way with LINQ:

```
var filtersList = GetFilteres();
var filteredData = data;
foreach (var filter in filtersList)
{
    filteredData = filter(filteredData);
}
```

NB: the filtered list is unknown at compile time. it will be populated at runtime.

Example:
Let's assume we have two filter functions, we get those functions at the startup of my application by reading the `app.config` file.

Filter 01 predicate : `x => x > 1 && x < 3`

Filter 02 predicate: `x => x > 2 < 10`

Data: a list of integers: `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]`

After passing this list to the first filter the output will be:
`[0,1,2]`

this output set will be the input of the second filter, So after applying the second filter the outputs will be `[0,1]`

Comment: Couldn't you use a set of chained `.Where()` methods?

Comment: What's the type of filterslist?

Comment: the filters list populated dynamically at runtime (e.g exported functions), so the set of filters are not known unless there is a way to chain .Where(...) using LINQ itself.

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar filterList is a set of ``Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumrable<T>>``

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please update the question with an example of item source and an example of what you need to get from these items

Comment: based on the edits it seems the type of filterlist is Func<int, bool> and not Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumrable<T>> as previously mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ there is a [`where filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) so you don't have to write an imperative code

`where` filter will run a predicate on each item in your Items source and if the predicate return true it will continue in the pipeline and if it returns false it will block this item from continue in the pipeline

```cs
// the follwing example will filter list of intgers to return all even nmber less than 6 in the Items 
IEnumerable<int> Items = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
IEnumerable<int> filterdItems = Items .Where(element=>element%2==0).Where(element=> element<6);
```

your question does not tell much on what you need specifically to do, I guess you try to do a projection not a filtration, in this case you have to look at [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) Method

Answer (score 0):

Combine the sequence of calls to the `Where` method, to which you pass the predicate `Func<T, bool>`.

```
var filters = new List<Func<int, bool>>();

filters.Add(n => n > 30 && n < 70);
filters.Add(n => n % 2 == 0);

var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
IEnumerable<int> result = data;

foreach (var filter in filters)
{
    result = result.Where(filter);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: Your solution has for each loop which the OP doesn’t need .

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of source items, and a sequence of Predicates that filter these source items.

So if your source is of type `T`, your predicates will all be `Func<T, bool>`.

You want a method that takes an input source, and returns only those items from the input source where every predicate will return true.

As an extension method (if you are not familiar with extension methods, read [extension methods demystified](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> predicates)
{
    // TODO: implement
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = ...

var predicates = new Func<Customer, bool>[]
{
    customer => !customer.IsDeleted,
    customer => customer.City == "New York",
    customer => customer.BirthDate.Year < 1960,
}

var oldNewYorkCustomers = customers.WhereAll(predicates).ToList();
```

The following implementation uses recursion:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> predicates)
{
    Func<T, bool> firstPredicate = predicates.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstPredicate != null)
    {
        // filter using the first predicate, and recursively call this method
        // without the first predicate
        return source.Where(firstPredicate)
                     .WhereAll(predicates.Skip(1));
    }
    else
    {
        // no predicates; nothing to filter
        return source;
    }
}
```

Although this seems a cool method, it has the disadvantage that the sequence of predicates is not enumerated efficiently. First it takes the first Predicate, then it starts again at the first predicate and skips this first element: the sequence of predicates will be enumerated twice.

if you use foreach on the sequence of predicates, instead of recursion with LINQ methods, the sequence of predicates will be enumerated only once:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> predicates)
{
    var returnValue = source;
    foreach (var predicate in predicates)
    {
        returnValue = source.Where(predicate);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

A third method would be to create an enumerator by using `yield return`: take the first element of the sequence, check if it passes all predicates, and if so, return it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> predicates)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicates.All(predicate => predicate(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this method is, that if you only want the first filtered item, all other items of the source are not touched:

```
var oldNewYorkCustomers = customers.WhereAll(predicates).FirstOrDefault();
```